# Code to generate bell curve is only creating data at even indexes. Why?

Tags: c

I'm writing some code to use random numbers to create a bell curve.

The basic approach is as follows:

Create an array of 2001 integers.

For some  number of repeats, do the following:

```
• Start with a value of 1000 (the center-value)
• Loop 1000 times
    • Generate a random number 0 or 1. If the random number is zero, subtract 1 from the value. If it's 1, add 1 to the value.
• Increment the count in my array at the resulting index value.
```

So 1000 times, we randomly add 1 or subtract 1 from a starting value of 1000. On average, we'll add 1 and subtract one about as often, so the outcome should be centered around 1000. Values greater or less than 1000 should be less and less frequent. A value at index 0 or index 1 would require a "coin toss" with the same result 1000 times in a row... a **VERY** unlikely event that is still possible.

Here is the code I came up with, written in C with a thin Objective C wrapper:

```
#import "BellCurveUtils.h"

@implementation BellCurveUtils

#define KNumberOfEntries 1000
#define KPinCount 1000
#define KSlotCount (KPinCount*2+1)

 static int bellCurveData[KSlotCount];


+(void) createBellCurveData;
{
  NSLog(@"Entering %s", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
  NSTimeInterval start = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate];

  int entry;
  int i;
  int random_index;

  //First zero out the data
  for (i = 0; i< KSlotCount; i++)
    bellCurveData[i] = 0;

  //Generate KNumberOfEntries entries in the array
  for (entry =0; entry<KNumberOfEntries; entry++)
  {
    //Start with a value of 1000 (center value)
    int value = 1000;

    //For each entry, add +/- 1 to the value 1000 times.
    for (random_index = 0; random_index<KPinCount; random_index++)
    {
      int random_value = arc4random_uniform(2) ? -1: 1;
      value += random_value;
    }
    bellCurveData[value] += 1;
  }
  NSTimeInterval elapsed = [NSDate timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate] - start;
  NSLog(@"Elapsed time = %.2f", elapsed);

  int startWithData=0;
  int endWithData=KSlotCount-1;
  for (i = 0; i< KSlotCount; i++)
  {
    if (bellCurveData[i] >0)
    {
      startWithData = i;
      break;
    }
  }
  for (i = KSlotCount-1; i>=0 ; i--)
  {
    if (bellCurveData[i] >0)
    {
      endWithData = i;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (i = startWithData; i <= endWithData; i++)
    printf("value[%d] = %d\n", i, bellCurveData[i]);
}

@end
```

The code does generate a bell-shaped curve. However, the array entries with odd indexes are ALL zero.

Here is some sample output:

```
value[990] = 23
value[991] = 0
value[992] = 22
value[993] = 0
value[994] = 20
value[995] = 0
value[996] = 25
value[997] = 0
value[998] = 37
value[999] = 0
value[1000] = 23
value[1001] = 0
value[1002] = 26
value[1003] = 0
value[1004] = 20
value[1005] = 0
value[1006] = 28
value[1007] = 0
value[1008] = 23
value[1009] = 0
value[1010] = 26
```

I have gone over this code line-by-line, and do not see why this is. When I step through it in the debugger, I get values that bounce around by single steps, starting at 1000, dropping to 999, incrementing to 1001, and various values even and odd. However, after 1000 iterations, the result of `value` is **always** even. What am I missing here?!?

I realize this isn't a typical SO development question, but I'm stumped. I cannot see what I am doing wrong. Can somebody explain these results?

Comment: Because `kPinCount` is even, you will never generate an odd index.

Comment: If you consider your random input as coin flips, you're basically adding the number of heads minus the number of tails. This sum always has the same parity (even- or odd-ness) as the number of trials. Consider a small trial count, like 4 - (#H, #T) can be (4, 0), (3, 1), (2, 2), (1, 3), (0, 4). In every case the difference is even.

Comment: Makes sense now that you explain it that way. If you post your reply as an answer I'll accept it. What is the mathematically "clean" way to generate all possible indexes then? The solution I came up with was to randomly perform either 1000 or 999 "coin flips" for each number I generate, which causes the "parity" of the result to be random, but would make the outer-most indexes (array[0] and array [2000] impossible to reach when the flip count is 999.

Comment: You could use [an already manufactured wheel](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Random-Number-Distributions.html), unless you are determined to use your own.

Comment: This was a learning exercise. The 2 obvious solutions to fix my program are to randomly do increment/decrement the value either 999 or 1000 times, or to add +1/0/-1 at each step.

Comment: @JoshCaswell, thanks for the suggestion of the GNU math library. The function gsl_ran_gaussian() is perfect. The only problem is that the theoretical range of output is -inifinity to +infinity, where my random-ball-drop method gives a range bounded by the number of random left/right steps. Now if only it wasn't using that pesky GNU software license. Gaussian distribution is very useful for game logic, when you want middle-of-the-road behavior to be the norm, with very easy and very difficult outcomes to be 2nd sigma or 3rd sigma occurrences.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
//For each entry, add +/- 1 to the value 1000 times.
for (random_index = 0; random_index<KPinCount; random_index++)
{
  int random_value = arc4random_uniform(2) ? -1: 1;
  value += random_value;
}
```

For any two iterations of this loop, there are three potential outcomes:

1. random_value is zero both times, in which case "value" decreases by 2.
2. random_value is one both times, in which case "value" increases by 2.
3. random_value is zero once and one once, in which case "value" is unchanged.

Therefore, if the loop runs an even number of times (i.e. KPinCount is an even number), the parity of "value" will never change. Since it begins as an even number (1000), it ends as an even number.

**Edit:** If you want to resolve the problem but keep the same basic approach, then rather than starting with value = 1000 and running 1000 iterations in which you either add or subtract one, perhaps you could start with value = 0 and run 2000 iterations in which you add either one or zero. I'd have posted this as a comment to the discussion above, but can't comment since I just registered.

Answer (score 1):

Youe immediate problem is at

```
for (random_index = 0; random_index < KPinCount; random_index++)
{
  int random_value = arc4random_uniform(2) ? -1: 1;
  value += random_value;
}
```

Because `KPinCount` is defined as 1000 (an even number), at the end of the loop, `value` will have changed by a multiple of 2.

Maybe try with `KPinCount` varying between 999 and 1000???

Comment: That is the solution I came up with, but I don't like it. I'm hoping for a mathematically "pure" solution.

Comment: Another solution I thought of would be to use random values from 0 to 2, where 0 means subtract 1, 1 means no change, and 2 means add 1 to my value. This would be "pure" but would reduce the amount of "drift" away from the center-point in my curve, and cause a more "pointy" curve.

Comment: Hmmm ... make the value change by `-1`, `0`, or `1`, maybe?

Comment: That's what I meant by my second reply to your answer.

Comment: Half the values should be no change. For every two iterations of your current loop there are 4 possibilities (-1, -1), (-1, 1), (1, -1), (1, 1). One increments, once decrements, and *two* stay the same. You should choose among *four* random values, not three: 0, 0, -1, +1. The number of iterations will determine the width of your distribution.

Comment: @rhashimoto, why half of the values = no change, instead of -1, 0, +1. Both would solve the "equal parity" problem, wouldn't they?

Comment: @DuncanC Both will get all your bins populated. Using four values preserves the distribution shape of your original code, just with all the odd bins removed.

Comment: @rhashimoto, gotcha. So using 3 values (-1/0/+1) would cause a flatter curve, and using 4 bins (-1/0/0/+1) would preserve the shape of the curve, but at the cost of having to do roughly twice as many iterations to get the same spread? Actually, wouldn't using -1/0/0/+1 values cause the curve to be "pointier", since in theory you could still hit the outermost points (+/-1000) after 1000 steps, but on average your points would be spread out 1/2 as much for those same 1000 steps?

Comment: @DuncanC Four values is going to give you a [binomial distribution](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RandomWalk1-Dimensional.html), like your original code, but without the odd bins. Yes, removing the odd bins does compress the domain. Three values is [more complicated](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/501950/one-dimensional-random-walk-with-possibility-to-stand-still) - I don't know if having a uniform distribution over those values simplifies the math.

Comment: @rhashimoto, come to think of it, wouldn't the cleanest solution be to use +1/-1, and then divide the final change in value by 2 before using it as an array index? (So I would start at 0, +1/-1 1000 times, divide the result by 2, then add 1000 to center it, and use **that** to increment an entry in my array.) That should give a totally pure result, where a 3-value or 4-value random number (+1/0/-1, or +1/0/0/-1) **DO** affect the shape of the curve, as illustrated in my answer to the thread.)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I've gotten some very useful feedback on this project.

To summarize:

If you always add or subtract one from a value, and do it twice, the possibilities are:

1. +1 +1 = even change
2. +1 -1 = no (even) change
3. -1 -1 = even change

Thus in that case the value always changes by 0 or 2, so result is always an even number.

Likewise, if you always apply an odd number of +1/-1 value changes, the resulting value will always be odd.

A couple of solutions were proposed.

Option 1: (The change I used in my testing) was before calculating each value, randomly decide to loop either 999 or 1000 times. That way half the time the result will be even and the other half of the time the value will be odd.

This has the effect that the spread of the graph will be infinitesimally narrower, because half of the time the possible range of values will be less by +/- 1.

Option 2 was to generate 3 random values, and add +1,0, or -1 to the value based on the result.

Option 3, suggested by @rhashimoto  in the comments to one of the other answers, was to generate 4 random values, and add +1,0, 0, or -1 to the value based on the result.

I suspected that options 2 and 3 would cause a narrower spread of the curve because for 1/3 or 1/4 of the possible random values on each iteration, the value would not change, so the average spread of values would be smaller.

I've run a number of tests with different settings, and confirmed my suspicions.

Here are graphs of the different approaches. All sample graphs are plots of 1,000,000 points, with the graph clamped to values ranging from 800 to 1200 since there are never values outside that range in practice. The green bars on the graph are at the center point and +/- 50 steps

First, option 1, which randomly applies either 999 or 1000 +/-1 changes to the starting value:

[image]

Option 2, 1000 iterations of applying 3 random possible changes, -1,0, or +1:

[image]

And option 3, 1000 iterations of  applying 4 random possible changes, -1,0, 0, or +1, as suggested by rhashimoto in the comments to pmg's answer:

[image]

And overlaying all the graphs on top of each other in Photoshop:

[image]

I have created graphs using a much larger number of points (100 million instead of 1 million) and the graphs are much smoother and less "jittery", but the shape of the curve is for all practical purposes identical. Applying a modest rolling average to the results from a one-million iteration graph would no doubt yield a very smooth curve.